# Django - How to get current item in the view

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have catalog of products, there is how its look like in *models.py*:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

This is product detail view.

```
def ProductDetailView(request, pk):
    productdetail = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'productdetail': productdetail})
```

And this is *urls.py* for product detail view:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProductDetailView, name='detail'),
```

Now I need to add an order button on product detail page. When user click on this button, the data with the order have to save to the database, so i made a new model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

And there is i realize it in the *view.py*:

```
user = request.user
r = Order.objects.create(customer_name = user, product = ?)
```

But I don't know how to save current `product`. I will be thankful if you will help me with it.

Comment: But you're already doing it in ProductDetailView. What is wrong with that?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get that i do it. But now i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the same process:

Define a new url for orders:

```
url(r'^order/product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.OrderView, name='order'),
```

Where `pk` param will be the product's pk.

And in your view:

```
user = request.user
product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
```